# IP адрес в Delphi

Tags: delphi, ip-address

Как программно узнать свой IP адрес?

Comment: >> Почему то не работает!!!

Как информативно ...

    function GetIP:string;
    begin
       Result := '127.0.0.1';
    end;

это 100% будет работать! :)

Comment: РЕАЛЬНО РАБОТАЕТ!!!!

Comment: > Почему то не работает!!!

У вас сетевой интерфейс-то, надеюсь, поднят?

Comment: @shurik эта функция не узнаёт свой IP, а подключается к своему компьютеру, а мне нужно УЗНАТЬ свой IP!!!

Comment: А разве Вам не сказали Ваш IP ещё в детском садике? IP-адрес имеет не хост, а интерфейс, которых у хоста (компьютера) может быть несколько: loopback (не считаем), одна или несколько сетевых карт (если они разбиты на подинтерфейсы -- ещё веселее), какой-нибудь ppp и т.д. Посмотрите вывод команды ipconfig.

Comment: Кстати да, можно еще запустить ipconfig и отпарсить вывод.

Answer (score 2):

Можно, например, так:

```
function GetIP:string;
var
  WSAData: TWSAData;
  p: PHostEnt;
  name: array [0..255] of AnsiChar;
begin
  WSAStartup($0101, WSAData);
  gethostname(name, 256);
  p := gethostbyname(name);
  result := inet_ntoa(PInAddr(P.H_ADDR_LIST^)^);
  WSACleanup;
end;
```

Comment: А попроще нельзя?!

Comment: А что тут сложного? 5 строчек - код и так уже урезан до минимума. На самом деле, тут еще нужно вставить несколько проверок.

Я подозреваю, можно через WinAPI получить список сетевых интерфейсов и получить их IP-адреса. Но это вряд ли будет попроще.

Comment: Почему то не работает!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
function TForm2.LocalIP: string;
type
 TaPInAddr=array [0..10] of PInAddr;
 PaPInAddr=^TaPInAddr;
var
 phe:PHostEnt;
 pptr:PaPInAddr;
 Buffer:array [0..63] of char;
 i:Integer;
 GInitData:TWSADATA;
begin
 WSAStartup($101, GInitData);
 Result:='';
 GetHostName(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
 phe:=GetHostByName(buffer);
 if phe=nil then Exit;
 pptr:=PaPInAddr(Phe^.h_addr_list);
 i:=0;
 while pptr^[i]<>nil do
  begin
   result:=StrPas(inet_ntoa(pptr^[i]^));
   Inc(i);
  end;
 WSACleanup;
end;
```

Comment: Почему то не работает!!!

Comment: что именно не работает, ошибка какая-то появляется?

Comment: Да ошибка! Пишет Undeclared indifier на каждом типе!

Answer (score 0):

```
uses
  WinSock;

function GetLocalIP: String;
const WSVer = $101;
var
  wsaData: TWSAData;
  P: PHostEnt;
  Buf: array [0..127] of Char;
begin
  Result := '';
  if WSAStartup(WSVer, wsaData) = 0 then begin
    if GetHostName(@Buf, 128) = 0 then begin
      P := GetHostByName(@Buf);
      if P <> nil then Result := iNet_ntoa(PInAddr(p^.h_addr_list^)^);
    end;
    WSACleanup;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Да, разумеется, надо WinSock подключить.